# Barra de menu colorida utilizando o Plugin Mega Main Menu?

Tags: wordpress, plugin, menu

Estou utilizando o plugin Mega Main Menu para configurar barra de menu no WordPress e gostaria de mudar a cor padrão, como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Na documentação do Plugin tem todas as informações que você precisa saber, recomendo que leia http://manual.menu.megamain.com/#menu_item_settings, se quiser encurtar da um CTRL+F e procure por Color